# Need help identifying a bike

Tags: identify-this-bike

We bought this bike from a boy scout camp in Baltimore MD called Broadcreek about 3 years ago. They were donated to the camp to be used by camp counselors.  We have contacted the camp but o one has any idea to their brand.  It was red but we painted it for my daughter.  We know the following, it has a rear disk brake, it is a 3 speed that shifts on the handle.  We were told it has "internal gears".  It is relatively new because it has a built in light on the front and back and they are LEDs'  The lights don't have a switch and we put in new batteries and the front flashed and then did not work.  She gets all kinds of questions about it ("is that electric?", "where did you get that thing?") and she would love to have an answer and get the lights working.  thank you in advance for your help.

A friend told me it may be from a bike share.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

We found it!  Somehow it came to Marlyand by way of Barcelona! http://www.barcelonayellow.com/bcn-transport/78-bicing-city-bikes[image]

Comment: I was going to say that it was probably a European design.

Comment: Great find - well done.  Consider marking this answer as "accepted" by clicking the green tick/check mark below the score, on the left side.  That tells SE's search engine that an answer was found.

Comment: Or from Antwerp, Belgium. http://l7.alamy.com/zooms/fb94ae4a347a49189005a4f0d358538e/a-row-of-velo-bicycles-for-hire-in-the-city-of-antwerp-dtjtkm.jpg To get the lights working you'll need to check if the buffering rechargeable battery or super-capacitor isn't defective.It is meant to keep the lights burning for a certain time after the bike has stopped.

Comment: @DanielRHicks: The wheels are of different sizes and have odd tyre dimensions that are almost impossible to buy as replacements and to avoid thieves cannibalizing the bikes.